# how to sum rows of csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-csv

I have the following code that retrieves the rows from a txt file, I would like to sum all the values ​​of item_price to be able to use it in my application. I'd like this value to be retrieved out of the block:

```
CSV.foreach(dir, col_sep: "\t", headers: true).map do |row|
```

Follow the code:

```
module ParseText
  def self.parse
    require 'csv'
    dir = Dir.glob("./public/system/file_attaches/files/*/*/*/*/*").max_by {|f| File.mtime(f)}
    CSV.foreach(dir, col_sep: "\t", headers: true).map do |row|
      records = row.to_h
      purchaser = records["purchaser name"]
      item_description = records["item description"]
      item_price = records["item price"]
      purchase_count = records["purchase count"]
      merchant_address = records["merchant_address"]
      merchant_name = records["merchant name"]

      Merchant.create(name: merchant_name)
      MerchantAddress.create(street: merchant_address, merchant_id: Merchant.last.id)
      Purchaser.create(name: purchaser, count: purchase_count, merchant_id: Merchant.last.id)
      Item.create(description: item_description, price: item_price, merchant_id: Merchant.last.id, purchaser_id: Purchaser.last.id )
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: why not just use `total_price += item_price` where you define `total_price = 0.0`.

Comment: What @Anthony says will work, but if you don't want to initialize a var outside of the block, you can achieve the result with `#inject`. See me answer for details.

Comment: @Anthony, when i try i get: String can't be coerced into Float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CSV.foreach(dir, col_sep: "\t", headers: true).inject(0) do |price_sum, row|
  # Leave the code you already have here
  price_sum += item_price.to_i
end
```

Comment: Humm...i try but i get this error: String can't be coerced into Fixnum

Comment: Your `item_price` must be a string. You need to cast it to a float or int. I'll update my code with the latter.

Comment: It's works, but how i can use the variable price_sum out of block?

Comment: The block returns the value you want. So if you need the value outside of it, assign it to a variable. `price = CSV.foreach...`.

Comment: Consider using [Enumerable#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) with the appropriate block (`row` being the only block variable). That method made its debut in Ruby v2.4.